# Conversion of data to json

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-esb

Please find enclosed 3 screenshots in one of above usecase in debug mode , I am trying to obtain the result in json format but I am getting the result as mentioned in lower screenshot in postman .

Please help .

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you add ObjectToJson converter as below

`<json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>`

Add this component at the end of your flow. This will solve the issue.